# my canvas I small when the size 1680x960

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

coords=1017,474
frame = Canvas(root, width=1680, height=960)


def cords(event):
    print(event.x,event.y)



def click(event):
    frame.create_line(event.x,event.y,coords)

frame.bind('<B1-Motion>',click)
frame.bind('<Button-1>',cords)


photo=PhotoImage('images.png')
label=Label(frame,image=photo)
label.grid(row=5,)

frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

when I run this code my window is the minimum size. could someone tell me why? and when it does work with ok size none of my bindings and images are there if.

Comment: do you expect the label to be inside or outside the canvas? Do you expect the canvas to grow and shrink when the window is resized? Do you expect to be able to scroll the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because of this line:

```
label.grid(row=5,)
```

This cause the parent window (in this case, the canvas) to shrink to fit the label.

There are many solutions, but it all depends on what behavior you expect, which is not clear in your question. Generally speaking you should not call `grid` or `pack` on a widget that is a child of a canvas. Typically you use the `create_window` method of the canvas to place a widget within the canvas.

There are other solutions, but the right solution depends on exactly how you plan to use the canvas and the label.

Comment: how do you use the create_window method